# Java regex help

Tags: java, regex

I have a string containing n substrings in the following format which I want to match:

```
{varName:param1, param2, param2}
```

Requirements are as follows:

1. Only the varName (inside the curly brackets) is mandatory
2. No limit on the number of parameters
3. No restrictions on whitespace inside curly brackets apart from var and param names which must not contain whitespace

I would like to be able to capture the varName and each of the parameters separately.

I have come up with a regex that is nearly there, but not quite. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say you've got a regex which is "nearly there". Perhaps you could post what you've managed so far?

Comment: Problem with this is that it matches the varName (group1) the first param (group2) and the last param (group3) only

Comment: \{([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\s*:\s*([^,\s]+))?(?:\s*,\s*([^,\s]+))*\s*\}

Comment: As every regex has a fixed number of groups, you can't use it to capture an unlimited number of substrings. You need some sort of loop or split.

Comment: Well that's that then :-) thx alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s = "blah blah\n{varName:param1, param2, param2}\nblah";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
  "\\{([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\s*:\\s*([^,\\s]+(?:\\s*,\\s*[^,\\s]+)*))\\}"
);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find())
{
  String varName = m.group(1);
  String[] params = m.start(2) != -1
                  ? m.group(2).split("[,\\s]+")
                  : new String[0];

  System.out.printf("var: %s%n", varName);
  for (String param : params)
  {
    System.out.printf("param: %s%n", param);
  }
}
```

If you're holding out for a way to match the string and break out all the components with one regex, don't bother; this is as good as it gets (unless you switch to Perl 6).  As for performance, I wouldn't worry about that until it becomes a problem.

Comment: Yep, thanks everyone for your help. I see now that I was barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering whether it would be easier to simply use `String.split()` judiciously, rather than battle with regexps for the above. The delimiters (colons/whitespace/commas) seem well-defined.

Comment: perhaps, though I do need to use a regex to find the whole patterns in the surrounding string, so thought I might as well match the inner parts at the same time

Comment: Agreed, regex really aren't the solution for this problem. Unreadable oneliners (and are there any other regexs?) are horrible to maintain and the syntax is simple enough to be easily parsed in a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex, AND a Scanner ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Regex {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    String string = "{varName: param1, param2, param2}";   
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
    scanner.useDelimiter("[\\s{:,}]+");
    System.out.println("varName: " + scanner.next());
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println("param: " + scanner.next());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that, haven't come across the Scanner class before. Reading up on it now.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution in psuedocode:

```
string.match(/{(\w+):([\w\s,]+)}/);
varName = matches[1];
params = matches[2].split(',');
```

Comment: yes, thought of that and this post was last hurrah before giving up and doing that. Worried a little about the performance of a separate split because it will be quite high volume - though, tbh, have no idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

Post what you have so far.
You can test it very easily on this website:
http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Comment: Added what I have got so far above

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've got a solution in regex that seems to work just fine:

\{\s*([^\{\},\s]+)\s*(?:(?::\s*([^\{\},\s]+)\s*)(?:,\s*([^\{\},\s]+)\s*)*)?\}

Or to even keep the pretense of being able to understand it:

name = [^\{\},\s]+

ws = \s*

\{ws(name)ws(?:(?::ws(name)ws)(?:,ws(name)ws)*)?\}

I wouldn't recommend it but short testing seems to indicate that it works - nice brain teaser for 3am in the morning ;)

PS: If you're comparing the split solution to this or something similar I'd be interested in hearing if there were any performance differences - I don't think regex would be especially performant.